# Read each directory and perform actions in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I have this directory structure at `/var/sync`:

```
# tree -d /var/sync/
/var/sync/
├── sync_bi
│   ├── replicator => Replicator.php
│   sync.php 
├── sync_pfizer
│   ├── replicator => Replicator.php
│   sync.php
│ replicator.sh
│ sync.sh
```

As you can see on each `sync_*` directory there is script called `sync.php` and on each `replicator` directory there is a script called `Replicator.php`. I need to run those scripts each night. `Replicator.php` should run at 00:00 AM and `sync.php` should run at 12:30 AM. I know the right path here is obviously a cron job. I have made two scripts `replicator.sh` and `sync.sh` sharing almost the same code the main difference is the script name. See code below:

```
replicator.sh
#! /bin/bash
cd $1
/usr/bin/php Replicator.php

sync.sh
#! /bin/bash
cd $1
/usr/bin/php sync.php
```

Then I have added each to cronjob as follow:

```
0 0 * * * /var/sync/replicator.sh /var/sync/sync_bi/replicator/
0 30 * * * /var/sync/sync.sh /var/sync/sync_bi/
0 2 * * * /var/sync/replicator.sh /var/sync/sync_pfizer/replicator/
30 2 * * * /var/sync/sync.sh /var/sync/sync_pfizer/
```

My idea behing all this explanation is to optimize my environment by changing script to just one that allow me to perform all the actions in just one cronjob call and keep less files to maintain. So I did a little research and I have found a helpful topics:

- By using `find some/dir -type f -execdir somecommand {} \;` is a proper way to achieve the same thing as I am doing with `cd`
- And by moving into each directory under root path - in my case `/var/sync`

  ```
   for D in ./*; do
      if [ -d "$D" ]; then
          cd "$D"
          run_something
          cd ..
      fi
  done
  ```

This is a pseudo code of what I am talking about (in case is not clear enough):

```
read tree structure at /var/sync
foreach (directory in root+path)
    if (directory_name is replicator)
        cd replicator/
        /usr/bin/php replicator.php
    else if (directory_name is sync_*)
        cd sync_*/
        /usr/bin/php sync.php
endforeach
```

I am not so bash expert so I am asking for some help to translate that pseudo code in something functional that allow me to achieve what I am looking for, any advice and/or help?

**UPDATE**

Perhaps I am wrong but I am not following at all what you guys are trying to do so here is the order of the events:

```
# Run Replicator at mid day and mid night
# this two can run at same time since they are pushing data to different DBs
/var/sync/sync_bi/replicator/Replicator.php
/var/sync/sync_pfizer/replicator/Replicator.php

# Run sync at mid day and mid night
# this two should run one first and the second after 30 min since they are 
# pushing data to the same DBs and second depends on first one
/var/sync/sync_bi/sync.php
/var/sync/sync_pfizer/sync.php
```

Having that info (and sorry for not clear this in first) how your solutions should works? As you have them right now or you need to change anything in order to cover this?

Comment: Do you also want to run `/var/sync/sync.sh` and `/var/sync/replicator.sh` or only the ones in the subdirectories? Will all `sync_*` directories contain a `replicator` subdirectory or could some of them not have one? Can the tree be more complex or will it always be a maximum of 2 deep? Can you have something like `/var/sync/foo/bar/baz/foo_sync/` for example?

Comment: Also, where in the pseudocode do you check whether it's 0:00 AM or 12:30 AM?

Comment: @terdon I do not want to run `/var/sync/sync.sh` either `/var/sync/replicator.sh` that will never happen. Yes, `syc_*` will always have a `replicator` directory inside. That's how the three looks like with no more deep rather than 2, what could happen here is the appearance of another `sync_*` dir with same structure as the rest of them and no for that last one of your questions

Comment: @choroba I think this is part of cronjob, the idea is to wait until parents tasks ends I don't have any idea in how to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be two `find` commands:

```
find /var/sync/ -name 'sync.php' -execdir php {} \;
find /var/sync/ -name 'Replicator.php' -execdir php {} \;
```

That will look for files called either `sync.php` or `Replicator.php`, then cd into their parent directory and execute them with `php`. You could add the commands directly to your crontab:

```
0 30 * * * find /var/sync/ -name 'sync.php' -execdir php {} \;
0 0 * * * find /var/sync/ -name 'Replicator.php' -execdir php {} \;
```

If you need the `Replicator` scripts to be run with a 30 minute pause between them, you could do something like:

```
find /var/sync/ -name 'Replicator.php' -execdir php {} \; -exec sh -c "sleep 30m" \;
```

That will first run the script, then wait for 30 minuntes before moving to the next one.

Finally, if you need to make sure that i) you never have >1 `sync.php` running at the same time and ii) each `sync` script is run after the corresponding `replicator` script has finished, you can use this as the command you give to cron:

```
find /var/sync/ -name 'Replicator.php' -execdir php {} \; ; find /var/sync/ -name 'sync.php' -execdir php {} \;
```

The above will run each of the `Replicator.php` scripts first (one after the other, not in parallel) and, once they've finished, will run each of the `sync.php` scripts.

Comment: I am still having a doubt here see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/paquitodev/d25fce53eac8b5f5e30f) where I try to run each script at mid day and mid night, right? Now if you look at `/var/sync` there are two `Replicator.php` and two `sync.php` scripts. How do I know which one is running or your solution will put both with same name running at same time? In that case for `Replicator.php` could work since uses different DB but for `sync` don't since use the same and scripts should be run one first then the next and so

Comment: @ReynierPM no, the scripts will be run sequentially, one after the other. Use the updated version (with `\;` instead of `+`) just to be sure, but the original should also have run them sequentially. I don't understand what you mean by knowing which one is running. Do you want some kind of log produced?

Comment: Many thanks, sorry while you was editing your answer I was editing my question so pls check the update and tell me if your recently update does that since that's exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: @ReynierPM if you really need to wait 30 whole minutes, see update. Otherwise, if you just need to run the second script after the first has finished, you can use the original version. Are you sure that 30 minutes are necessary?

Comment: I don't need to wait the whole 30 min this is just a approximated period I just need to wait until the previous script ends its execution, so which one to take on this case?

Comment: @ReynierPM the first. `find` will only execute the next script once the first one has ended.

Comment: ok, let's see if I am following you on this; I do not need to wait 30 min to run each script I just did this on first because I unknown how to achieve. You're telling me that scripts run sequentially so, first doubt: if I run `Replicator.php` the `sync.php` will not run until the execution of `Replicator.php` ends, is that right? second doubt: the `find` command will look for each `Replicator.php` and `sync.php` scripts under `/var/sync` right? Third doubt: should I leave the cronjob as you wrote on your answer or should I change it for something like ...

Comment: ... `0 0 * * * find /var/sync/ -name 'Replicator.php' -execdir php {} \;
0 0 * * * find /var/sync/ -name 'sync.php' -execdir php {} \;`, which one is the right?

Comment: @ReynierPM OK, we really should chat to clear this up but I don't have time now. Try going into the [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux), maybe someone there can help. Otherwise, I'll be happy to help later tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: I can wait until tonight or tomorrow just let me know as soon as you can and I'll be there, thanks

Comment: @ReynierPM ping me in chat when you're available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31151/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-terdon).

Answer (score 3):

This translates your pseudocode to bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/sync
for dir in sync*/ ; do
    ( # Subshell to make "cd" not global.
        cd "$dir"
        [[ -f sync.php ]] && /usr/bin/php sync.php
        if [[ -d replicator ]] ; then
            cd replicator
            [[ -f replicator.php ]] && /usr/bin/php replicator.php
        fi

    )
done
```

It runs both the sync.php and replicator.php at the same time, though, but you originally wanted to call them at different times. Maybe something like

```
#!/bin/bash

run=$1

cd /var/sync
for dir in sync*/ ; do
    ( # Subshell to make "cd" not global.
        cd "$dir"
        [[ -f "$run" ]] && /usr/bin/php "${run##*/}"
    )
done
```

called from cron like

```
0 30 * * * /path/to/script.sh sync.php
0 0 * * * /path/to/script.sh replicator/Replicator.php
```

`${run##*/}` removes everything before the last `/`, i.e. returns just the basename.

### Update

If you want to run the scripts as follows:

```
0:00 sync_a/sync.php
0:30 sync_a/replicator/Replicator.php
1:00 sync_b/sync.php
1:30 sync_b/replicator/Replicator.php
2:00 sync_c/sync.php
...
```

etc., you can just regenerate the crontab every time you change the directory structure:

```
#!/bin/bash
add=$1
php=/usr/bin/php
hour=0
minute=0

update_time () {
    (( minute += add ))
    if (( minute >= 60 )) ; then
        (( hour += minute / 60 ))
        (( minute %= 60 ))
    fi
    if (( hour > 11 )) ; then
        echo "Can't fit into a day!"
        exit 1
    fi
}
cd /var/sync

for dir in sync*/ ; do
    if [[ -f "$dir"/sync.php ]] ; then
        echo $minute $hour 0 0 0 "$php" /path/to/run.sh "$dir" sync.php
        update_time

        if [[ -f "$dir"/replicator/Replicator.php ]] ; then
            echo $minute $hour 0 0 0 "$php" path/to/run.sh "$dir" Replicator.php
        fi
        update_time
    fi
done
```

Call as `generate_crontab.sh 30` or similar. Note that some of the dirs could get skipped after a change, as the files are sorted alphabetically.

`run.sh` should just

```
dir=$1
script=$2
if [[ -f "$dir$script" ]] ; then
    cd "$dir"
    /usr/bin/php $script
fi
```

Comment: Excellent but I want to add more thing, the first script to be run on each subdirectory should be `Replicator.php` and 30m after this I should run `sync.php` so in my case the order should be: `00:00 AM => run /sync_bi/replicator/Replicator.php 00:30 AM => run /sync_bi/sync.php 01:00 AM run /sync_pfizer/replicator/Replicator.php 01:30AM run /sync_pfizer/sync.php`

Comment: In fact I do like to run all in just one script so I made just one cronjob call starting at 00:00 AM and then running next script each 30min (this mins could be a configurable parameter on the script since that time can change)

Comment: Having a script running for hours makes the system unreliable.

Comment: @ReynierPM: Check the update.

Comment: Many thanks, sorry while you was editing your answer I was editing my question so pls check the update and tell me if your recently update does that since that's exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: @ReynierPM: I don't understand your update. It seems to contradict your first comment to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31101/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-choroba).

Answer (score 1):

```
{   cat >    sync.sh  
    ln -s    sync.sh replicator.sh 
    chmod +x sync.sh
} <<"" 
#!/bin/sh
cmd=${0%.*}
cmd=${cmd##*/}
find /var/sync -name "$cmd.php" -exec /usr/bin/php {} \;
```

So when you call a shell script the shell sets the special shell parameter `$0` to the name of the script it reads, as a C program would set `argv[0]`. You're halfway there already in that you're running two scripts each named for its wrap target. But you don't need two scripts if you have two names - so you can just symlink the same script to the second name and refer to `$0` when you call it.

For `cron` you need only

```
i=-30
for  s in sync replicator
do   echo "0 $((i+=30)) * * * /var/sync/$s.sh" | crontab
done
```