# Change events order in bash script that writes to crontab

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

Coming from the solution on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240746/read-each-directory-and-perform-actions-in-bash-script/240758#240758) post I have made a few changes to the original script but output is not like it should be. Below is the script as I have right now:

```
#!/bin/bash
add=$1
php=/usr/bin/php
hour=0
minute=0

update_time () {
    (( minute += add ))
    if (( minute >= 60 )) ; then
        (( hour += minute / 60 ))
        (( minute %= 60 ))
    fi
    if (( hour > 23 )) ; then
        echo "Can't fit into a day!"
        exit 1
    fi
}

cd /var/sync

echo -e 'Display current crontab\n---------------------------------------------------\n'
(crontab -l)

echo -e 'Erasing current crontab\n---------------------------------------------------\n'
(crontab -r)

echo -e 'Generating new crontab\n---------------------------------------------------\n'

for dir in sync*/ ; do
    if [[ -f "$dir"/sync.php ]] ; then
        echo -e $minute $hour * * * "$php" /var/sync/run.sh "$dir" sync.php '\n'
        (crontab -l ; echo "$minute $hour * * * "$php" /var/sync/run.sh "$dir" sync.php") | sort - | uniq - | crontab -
        update_time

        if [[ -f "$dir"/replicator/Replicator.php ]] ; then
            echo -e $minute $hour * * * "$php" /var/sync/run.sh "$dir" Replicator.php '\n'
            (crontab -l ; echo "$minute $hour * * * "$php" /var/sync/run.sh "$dir" Replicator.php") | sort - | uniq - | crontab -
        fi
        update_time
    fi
done

echo -e 'Display current crontab\n---------------------------------------------------\n'
(crontab -l)
```

The current output for the script is:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_bi/ sync.php
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_pfizer/ Replicator.php
20 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_bi/ Replicator.php
20 1 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_sandbox/ sync.php
40 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_pfizer/ sync.php
40 1 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_sandbox/ Replicator.php
```

When it should be:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_bi/ Replicator.php
20 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_bi/ sync.php
40 1 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_pfizer/ Replicator.php
1 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_pfizer/ sync.php
20 1 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_sandbox/ Replicator.php
40 1 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/sync/run.sh sync_sandbox/ sync.php
```

Meaning first run the `Replicator.php` script and after run the `sync.php` script each one between 20 min starting at 00:00AM and the same should be repeat at 12:00PM, what is wrong on the code?

The idea behind that code is to write directly in crontab also show the result as output in the console some lines to run each task in the hour/minutes. That script above allow to do that but in some point if failing. As I said I took this from a previous answer I get in the post I told at the beginning of this post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what your final objective is. The code you show is very complex for what should be a simple task. While it's great that you've shown us what you tried, you also need to clearly explain what you are trying to do. If I understand your previous question correctly, you need some scripts to be launched after the previous ones have ended. [Edit] your question and explain what your exact objectives are.

Comment: @terdon better now?

Comment: Thanks for the edit but, no that's still not very clear :). You need to explain what you want to do. It looks like you want to run all scripts 20 minutes after one another. Is that correct? Why do you need 20 minutes? Isn't it enough to run the 2nd script only after the 1st has finished, the 3rd after the 2nd and so on?

Comment: @terdon yes, you're right take a look to the other question I am planning to move into your solution instead this one

Comment: @ReynierPM why not just write (or generate) a shell script that runs the tasks one after each other in the correct order and then run that from cron?  shell scripts are just text files (made executable with `chmod +x`) and can be generated just like config files.  You can even write the shell script so that the next task only runs if the previous task completed successfully.